# When replying to messages regarding jobs, will each option provide an opportunity to input a custom message?

Tags: support, feature-request, stack-overflow-jobs, user-interface, jobs-messages

The two (2) available options presented for action on a message regarding employment are both very vague and limited:

- *I'm Interested* - Can I include a custom message with the reply?
- *I'm Not Interested* - Will I have the ability to explain why?

[image: Options for message reply]

If these options do allow custom messaging then why not allow for the message before choosing your option (like a traditional email reply)? Without knowing I'll be provided a chance to include a message, I'm hesitant to respond therefore I decide best to ignore the messages.

Either path, reply without custom message or ignore, could be seen as rude. Some clarity and/or interface changes in this area would increase usefulness.